# Find out if there is an internet connection without requiring the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there a way to find out in Android if there is currently an active internet connection without having to include the [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) permission into the manifest an hence avoiding to use [NetworkInfo.isConnected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#isConnected()), and neither pinging a server?

We don't need to perform network operations, only to know if there is an active internet connection.

Comment: you could ask your user, something like ``hey, do you have a stable internet connection on your phone?`

Comment: *We don't need to perform network operations* - yes you do, it is the only way to determine if there is connection to the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not access any type of information of the device without user permission in android. If you  want to access user Network state you have to add the permission in your project manifests file.

Comment: Ehm, you can access a great deal of information of the device without user permission. E.g. via `Build`